# Select Dropdown issue on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm implementing an dropdown in an application, on IE 11 it doesn't work. The option box enlarges in width.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your code .. or `fiddle`link  so its easy for us to solve the issue.